# Two Wi-Fi networks on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Android

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, android, wifi-direct

I'm trying to see if there is a way that I can have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Android connected to two wi-fi networks at once?

What I'm trying to do is to get a feed from a camcorder (which frustatingly creates its own Wi-Fi network) onto a Raspberry Pi which would be running the relevant apps in Android and then send it to a remote computer that is on another Wi-Fi network.

Is there a way that I can achieve this? I know at the least I would need a USB Wi-Fi adapter which I have but are there any other technical limiations that would make this impossible to achieve? If it is impossible to achieve, is there another way that I could achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to the extent that the two wifi networks do not interfere with one another physically.